# How to change background image other than recieved id

Tags: javascript, php, xml

i have two files
xml.php and agent.xml
data in agent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<agents>
    <agent>
    <image> img/sara.jpg</image>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Tommy Jenkin</name>
    <company>CJenkins Insurance</company>
    <street>Insurance150 S State Stree</street>
    <city>Linkend</city>
    <phone>(773) 561-4331</phone>
    </agent>
    <agent>
    <image> img/primary-nav-logo.png</image>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>saka</name>
    <company>LIC Insurance</company>
    <street>Insurance150 S State Stree</street>
    <city>Linkend</city>
    <phone>(773) 561-4331</phone>
    </agent>
</agents>
```

and i am displaying this data through xml.php file 
the code in my xml.php file is given below

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("agent.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
            foreach($xml as $agent){
            function processXML($node){
                foreach($node->children() as $agent => $data){
                    $agent= trim($agent);   
                    if($agent!="" && $agent=='id')
                    {
                         echo '<div class = "inline">';
                         echo '<input type = "button" name="Agent" id = "'.$data.'" class = "subs-btn" value = "Select this Agent" OnClick = Selected(this.id);>';
                         echo '</div>';
                         echo '<div>';
                    }
                    elseif($agent!="" && $agent=='image')
                    {
                        echo '<div class = "inline"><img src="'.$data.'" ></div>';
                        echo '<div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                    elseif($agent!="")
                    {
                        echo '<div class = "inline">';
                        echo $data;
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<br/>';
                    }
                    processXML($data);
                    }
                }  
            processXML($xml);
            }
```

now at each agent to be displayed i am generating button with following code

```
echo '<input type = "button" name="Agent" id = "'.$data.'" class = "subs-btn" value = "Select this Agent" OnClick = Selected(this.id);>';
```

in this button i am calling the function of javascript which is given below by that code i am changing the background image of button.

```
function Selected(elem) 
                {
                    alert(elem);
                    document.getElementById(elem).style.backgroundImage="url('images/subs-btn-act.png')";
                    unselected();
                }
```

Now i am confused how to change the image of all other button to default image. I mean if i am click one button then background image of that particular button should be change. and after that if i am click another button the first clicked button should change the background image to default.

Please suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the previously selected button and change its bg-image back to your default when selecting a new one.
Change back to default by clearing the assigned bg-image:

```
function Selected(elem) 
{
 if(previous) { document.getElementById(previous).style.backgroundImage=""; }
 document.getElementById(elem).style.backgroundImage="url('images/subs-btn-act.png')";
 previous = elem; // remember current selection
 unselected();
}
```